# I have to send file as well as some json data to server using axios and decode it into express server to store json in mongodb and file using multer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios, multer

I want to create an endpoint which should store file on server side as well as the some json data which should be received from same point is to be stored on mongodb.
I am using axios to send request from React App. Here is my Code.

```
  const [companyFile, setCompanyFile] = useState(null);
  const [company, setCompany] = useState({
    name: "",
    websiteUrl: "",
    email: "",
    companyLocation: "",
  });

  const AddCompany = async (e) => {
    if (companyFile) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("company-file", companyFile);
      formData.append("company", JSON.stringify(company));

      axios({
        method: "post",
        url: `http://localhost:8080/company/add`,
        data: formData,
        withCredentials: true,
        header: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      }).then((res) => console.log(res.data));
    } else {
      console.log("file not selected!!!!");
    }
  };
```

Now I don't know how to check if it is coming to backend express server or not? Or if coming then how to retrive `application/json` data from request for further process.

My question is that if data is sent to backend express then how to process that data in backend (i.e. get json data to create an document in mongodb).
Here is my code for `company/add`

```
let upload = multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: async (req, file, cb) => {
      if (!company) {
        throw Error("Company cannot be found!");
      }
      let companyName = req.company.name;
      let path = `./uploads/${companyName}/files`;
      if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(path, { recursive: true });
      }
      cb(null, path);
    },
    filename: async (req, file, cb) => {
      //  ** with student auth Code

      req.filename = req.company.name;
      cb(null, filename + path.extname(file.originalname));
    },
  }),
}).single("company-file");

// Add Company
module.exports.add_company = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Here I want to extract that company object to create new company
    console.log(req.file);
    try {
      const newcompany = await Company.create(company);
      req.company = newcompany;
      upload(req, res, async () => {
        try {
          const companyFile = await CompanyFile.create({
            companyId: req.company._id,
            path: `./uploads/${req.company.name}/file/${req.filename}.pdf`,
          });
          req.companyFile = companyFile;
        } catch (err) {
          res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: err.message });
          // ** code for resume-upload using student authentication middleware
          if (
            fs.existsSync(
              `./uploads/${req.company.name}/file/${req.filename}.pdf`
            )
          ) {
            fs.unlink(`./uploads/${req.company.name}/file/${req.filename}.pdf`);
          }
        }
      });
      res.status(201).json({
        success: true,
        message: "Company Drive Added Successfully.",
        company: req.company,
        companyFile: req.companyFile,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(400).json({
        success: false,
        errors: err,
        message: "Error while applying company drive.",
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: Did I get you right? you just want to check if the response from the express server is a 200? I mean you already send it to the backend and console.log the result.

Comment: @187nitro I think he means he wants to get `company` data on the server as JSON instead of a string maybe? @Rohit can you clarify your question?

Comment: Please clearify, you're getting the result in the .then function, your console should read 200 is ok, or provide the code in company/add

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have given backend code also now in edit. So, I want to get company details in backend so how can i get it. I have tried as `let company = req.body`, but that not worked here. so, that is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#usage):

> Multer adds a body object and a file or files object to the request
> object. The body object contains the values of the text fields of the
> form, the file or files object contains the files uploaded via the
> form.

So in your case, you can access and parse the `company` field by doing:

```
const company = JSON.parse(req.body.company);
```

Also, you need to make sure to apply the `multer` middleware to your controller, e.g.

```
app.post('/company/add', upload.single('company-file'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `company-file` file
  // req.body.company will hold the company text field
})
```

Comment: `console.log(req.body.company) // undefined` means company details are not in body part of req. in documentation it says text field in form but i want to send a whole object, so, how to do it.

Comment: On the client side you do `JSON.stringify`, so it will be sent as a text-field. Are you sure it is defined on the client side? Maybe do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(company))` there as well to debug it.

Comment: I have checked `console.log(JSON.stringify(company))` , and it gives a string but in server side `req.body.company` is giving undefined.

Comment: i have also give server side code in question.

Comment: I took a closer look at the backend code and honestly - it's a bit of a mess. First you're trying to access company before you've even called the multer middleware. Then you're mixing async/await with callbacks, which won't work. My advice - start simple with the code I gave you and check if the file and fields exist in the request and continue from there.

Comment: Now I am getting company details after applying on middleware. but now, problem is that i want to change location and name of file based on textfields received from request. and in configuration of multer now textfields attached to request are being undefined.

Comment: That is a new problem and has nothing to do with the original question. You can accept my answer by clicking the checkmark on the left and create a new question with an updated problem description.